# Android Simple Data Sharing

Tags: android, mobile-development

I'm investigating ways to securely share small amounts of data between apps, ideally I would limit this to apps signed by the same developer.

We wouldn't have the concept of a central hub app so using intents or content providers doesn't seem to work since there would be no logical place for the data to sit.

Ideally we need a mechanism like the keychain on iOS.

I know that a shared user ID is a potential option but this seems dangerous since it involves apps sharing a process.

Does anyone have any ideas on a good approach to have some simple shared storage between apps that is secure and doesn't involve one app owning the data?

**Update:**

I was coming to the conclusion that the way to do this was to put encrypted data into shared preferences.

However I've just seen that the World Readable and World Writable modes have been deprecated so I'm questioning whether this would be a good long term solution, does that deprecation mean sharing files between apps like this is now not a viable option?

Comment: "since it involves apps sharing a process" -- no, it doesn't. It's dangerous because you can never change it, including adding a `sharedUserId` after having shipped without one.

Comment: Well either way it means a shared user ID isn't going to work as this would need to apply to apps we've already shipped.